# New MacBook Pro won't wake from sleep without restart

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake

My girlfriend's new MacBook Pro will *sometimes* seem not to wake up from sleep. No amount of spacebar hits, enters, clicks, etc. seem to awake the computer. She's resorted to hard restarting the computer which is obviously not ideal.

It seems to happen regardless of its state as it goes to sleep (closed lid, idle).

Anyone else hear of this or have any ideas?

Comment: Not a fix, but usually if you put it BACK to sleep it also will come back, the same thing happens to me with iMacs all the time where the screen lights up and no login is presented, all black. I just press the power button on the back to put it back to sleep and it wakes back up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem and is caused by the EFI being out of date. To fix this simple download and install [MacBook Pro EFI Firmware Update 1.9](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1098)

Hope this helps. All the best.

Comment: I'll give that a shot and check back. Thanks much!